# Plugin and "this" and scope and working around it with a global

Tags: jquery

So, this is not a 'new' problem but I can't seem to locate a solution other than creating some global. But if i have more than 1 instance, that global will collide with other plugin instances. For example.

```
;(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    var self = {};
    function Niftyplugin(elem, config){
        this.config = $.extend( {}, $.fn.niftyplugin.config, config );
        this.elem = elem;
        this.$elem = $( elem );
        self.config = this.config;
    }
}
```

I can circumvent the continuous need to do things like this:

```
var that = this;
```

in functions that would create scope issues, but as you see - I am using a global

`var self = {};` or any other name I could use.

My question is, is there a better way? A more robust way in which my plugin can assign the "this" obj in the constructor that won't collide with other instances to some var/obj ?

I tried...

```
;(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    var self = {};
    function Niftyplugin(elem, config, _self){  // <-- passing in _self
        this.config = $.extend( {}, $.fn.niftyplugin.config, config );
        this.elem = elem;
        this.$elem = $( elem );
        _self.config = this.config; // <-- _self
    }
 }


Niftyplugin.prototype = {
   // all the methods, and subsequently in some methods I'd have to use
   // var that = this. In situations of scope. I want to not do this and 
   // make my plugin self-contained with no global vars. But I want to circumvent 
   // need to assign "this" to vars etc..
}

$.fn.niftyplugin = function( config ) {
    if(this.length){
        this.each(function() {
            var nifty = new Niftyplugin( this, config, {} ); // <-- passing in obj
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I am being clear.

**EDIT:**
For more clarity.

Lets say, in my method instantions... I have something like:

```
Niftyplugin.prototype = {
     _create : function(){
         $(someobj).each(function(){
             self.someVar <------ this gives me an error. "self" is undefined.
          })
     }
}
```

This is my issue. Even though I declare "var self" in the constructor it isn't inherited into the prototype methods. This is what confuses me. Now, if I declare "var self" as a global var and then assign this to it in the constructor, its fine. BUT, I do not want to mess with the global space (even if it is sitting in the anonymous func).

Now, if I do something like

```
Niftyplugin.prototype = {
     _create : function(){
         var self = this;
         $(someobj).each(function(){
             self.someVar <------ this works
          })
     }
}
```

But I want to circumvent always have to do do a var self = this in every prototype method. Thus my need for a "this" equivalent var that I can declar in the constructor or pass in etc... that i can use. And if I have various elements using the plugin, that var won't clash.

Comment: It sure looks like you're overthinking and misuing `this`.  When `$.fn.niftyplugin` is called like `$(something).niftyplugin()`, the value of `this` will be set to a new jQuery object.  Why do you need or expect it to be your own object.  It is not clear what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: There are more than a few instances in which I am looping or function calling within these methods and inevitably scope issues happen. So, instead of always having to overcome that by doing "var that = this" and then doing something like: that.config.somevalue, I can just have a global namespace within the plugin so I don't have to make these assignments to overcome scope issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still haven't described what problem you're really trying to solve and I suspect that if we understood that, we could suggest much more elegant ways of solving it than what you're trying to force here.

A jQuery method is meant to be a method of a jQuery object.  Thus when, it is called, it has `this` set to the current jQuery object which is being operated on.  That is how jQuery methods are designed and how they work.  You either want your method to be a jQuery method that works like this or you don't.

If you just want your jQuery method to have access to some global state, then you can do that like this:

```
(function() {

    // Set up protected global state for my plugin method
    // This data is available only inside this closure.
    // It is global in nature, but is not actually available in the global scope.
    var myData = {};
    myData.whatever = "foo";
    myData.whomever = "joe";

    // define the new jQuery method
    $.fn.niftyplugin = function( config ) {
        // you can access myData state here
        if(this.length){
            this.each(function() {
                // whatever code you need here
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

This creates a closure with some variables in that closure that are available only to your plugin method.

Beyond this definition of some global state, you haven't described what other problem you might be actually trying to solve.  Please describe things in terms of the real problem, not the javascript solution you're trying to forge because your current attempt at a solution looks overly complicated or misdirected or at least the problem isn't explained well enough for us to know what to suggest.

---

If, on the other hand, what you want is per-instance data that is separate for each jQuery object that the plugin method gets called on, then, you can do that like this:

```
(function() {

    // Set up protected global state for my plugin method
    // This data is available only inside this closure.
    // It is global in nature, but is not actually available in the global scope.
    var myData = {};

    // define the new jQuery method
    $.fn.niftyplugin = function( config ) {
       // set instance data on the jQuery object itself
       this.whatever = "foo";
       this.whomever = "joe";
       var self = this;

        if(this.length){
            this.each(function() {
                // inside this callback function, this is a DOM element
                // self is the jQuery obect
                // whatever code you need here
                // you can access self.whatever or self.whomever
                // to get access to instance data on this jQuery object
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

---

Or, if you just need some data for the duration of your plugin method, you can just use local variables like this:

```
(function() {

    // Set up protected global state for my plugin method
    // This data is available only inside this closure.
    // It is global in nature, but is not actually available in the global scope.
    var myData = {};

    // define the new jQuery method
    $.fn.niftyplugin = function( config ) {
       // set instance data on the jQuery object itself
       var whatever = "foo";
       var whomever = "joe";

        if(this.length){
            this.each(function() {
                // inside this callback function, this is a DOM element
                // whatever code you need here
                // you can access whatever or whomever
                // to get access to local variables during this method call
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

---

Since you've added more to your question, here's some more info.  If you have this type of construct:

```
Niftyplugin.prototype = {
     _create : function(){
         var self = this;
         $(someobj).each(function(){
             self.someVar <------ this works
          })
     }
}
```

And you want access to the object instance inside the `each()` callback, then your best bet is to do what you are with the saving of `this` into a separate local variable like `self`.  `this` is reassigned to something else in the `.each()` callback so if you want access to the original `this`, then you have to save it somewhere else.  If you want to do that cleanly without globals (which is the recommendation), then you must do it in a local variable that is in scope of the callback function.  In the code snippet you've offered here, your only option to do this cleanly is by adding `var self = this` to each method.

---

It is possible to use different constructs that share a common `self`.

```
function Niftyplugin() {
    var self = this;

    this._create = function() {
        $(someobj).each(function(){
            self.someVar <------ this works
        })
    }

    this._update = function() {
        this.each(function(){
            self.someVar <------ this works
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. Ok, so in your example - you have myData. Now, lets say you instantiate the plugin on an element. Ok, lets say, on the same page, you do it again - diff. element. MyData (I believe) would class between the two plugins if myData was modified on the fly by either. yes?

Comment: @jamesemanon - `myData` is designed to be global state- one piece of data for all your instances.  That's the point of doing it that way.  If you want state on the object, use properties on the object itself such as `this.whatever = "foo";`.

Comment: @jamesemanon - I added two more options which I think should cover the range of options.

Comment: thank you very much for you detailed answers. I appreciate it. I edited my OP with more detail. I will experiment with what you wrote, perhaps you have solved my confusion. But I updated my question anyways just in case I was not succinct enough. Thanks again.

Comment: @jamesemanon - I've added more to the end of my answer.  I don't know why you're going to such great pains to try to avoid the `var self = this` in different methods.  It is the clean way of solving your issue.

Comment: @jamesemanon - it is possible to use different constructs (not the prototype) to create methods that share a common `self` variable.  I've added that to my answer too.

Comment: ok, to be honest, I was looking for something that would be a bit more robust, but I think you are right. I am going thru great pains to avoid some var reassignments. Not sure if the cost/benefit is worth all this trouble.. lololol. I think as I move forwad, I should have this in mind to then decide if I want to go the prototype way or more of a function obj way . Thanks a bunch for your explainations. You are very thorough.!